# import sympy doesn't work

Tags: python, sympy

I can import sympy fine in the terminal but once I save it as a .py file and run it, it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Dao/Desktop/sympy.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sympy import Symbol
File "/Users/Dao/Desktop/sympy.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sympy import Symbol
ImportError: cannot import name Symbol
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
```

I'm a little confused as why this is happening... Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This path:

```
/Users/Dao/Desktop/sympy.py
```

makes it look like you have your own file called `sympy.py`.  If that's true, then it's shadowing the library `sympy`.  In other words, when you type `from sympy import Symbol`, Python thinks *your* program is the one you want to import `Symbol` from, which won't work.

(1) Rename your program, and (2) delete any `Desktop/sympy.pyc` or `Desktop/sympy.pyo` files you have hanging around.  Then, if `sympy` is correctly installed (and from the fact you say that it can be imported, it probably is), it should work:

```
>>> from sympy import Symbol
>>> Symbol
<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
```

Answer (score 1):

sympy doesnt have the `Symbol` class directly . Its under core module.

you can import it by `from sympy.core.symbol import Symbol`

Note that sympy module is included in your python path.

Comment: No, actually Symbol is imported in the sympy namespace, so `from sympy import Symbol` should work.